# Is it possible to check how full a FileSystemWatcher buffer is?

Tags: c#, buffer, filesystemwatcher

I'm debugging a (common it seems) problem with FileSystemWatcher handling large volumes of file changes. I know you can set the buffer size up to 64K using InternalBufferSize.

But is there a way to check how much of that buffer is used?

Thanks

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is known for its deficiency, there's not a lot to 'fix' about it, only being extremely fine-grained and limited with use of it. Recommendations tend to be to use something else for performance _and_ reliability.

Comment: @GrantThomas: What is this "something else"? Are there any alternate implementations? Do you have a write-up of the deficiencies of `FileSystemWatcher`? I never heard of them but than I rarely need to use this class anyway.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Hm, I've had this problem before so there's a [cheap managed implementation](http://mchangejournal.codeplex.com/) of the [Change Journal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx) API, and doubtless countless other solutions more properly done (a Google search quickly turns up results). This is limited to NTFS; FAT have a long history chronicling direct disk access. I don't have a write up on FSW, but [the MSDN doc is honest enough to make one consider avoidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Comment: Practically, the internal buffer size is always entirely used in terms of memory usage. That's why you have to be careful not to set it too big, since it cannot be paged to disk. To answer your question: no, there is no way to check how much of the buffer contains relevant data.